# Shutil.move - First run Error, second run success

Tags: python, ioerror, shutil

I looked for similar issues in this forum, but not came up with my situation.
I program python with Eclipse. I am using shutil.move to move some files from one directory to another. When I run the code first, it is giving me the following error. Right after this I run a second try (without changing anything), it finds me the correct files and move to the correct place. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? If my code is faulty, why it is running in second try without any problem? The source and destination directories are already existing.

Here is the IOError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\john\workspace\RC\src\Test.py", line 82, in <module>
shutil.move('C:/RCTemp/' + filename, dest_sonst)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\shutil.py", line 302, in move
copy2(src, real_dst)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
copyfile(src, dst)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/RCTemp/Details.xslm'
```

And this is my code:

```
import os
import shutil

dest_dkfrontend = 'C:/RhodeCode/11_Detailkonzept_Frontend/'
  for filename in source:
   if filename.startswith('Details'):
  print('Files found ' + filename)
   shutil.move("C:/RhodeCodeTemp/" + filename, dest_dkfrontend)
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Indentation is part of logic in python, please fix yours, it's obviously broken.

Comment: You are correct, but if you just ignore indentation (as said the code is working in second try), what else you would recommend?

Comment: What do you mean "ignore it"? Logic is broken, I know how it's supposed to be, but it doesn't mean it is like that in your original code. Maybe all your problems come from indentation. Additionally, how is `source` variable declared?

Comment: You could also mention that you are using Windows. Windows uses backlashes "\" in paths, and you have an exception with "/" in your call. Try to change them and the code might just work. Also I have no idea why it works the second time.

Comment: No success with changing to or "/" or "\".

Comment: you refused to communicate, you are just saying "ignore it, but show me why it doesn't work", I say something you are ignoring could be a problem itself.